# Organising Rails source files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If i want to move **/lib/foo_bar.rb** to **/lib/tidy/foo_bar.rb** or even **/lib/tidy/somestuff/foo_bar.rb**

must i declare **FooBar** to be **module Tidy** or **module Tidy::Somestuff**

*in other words* must the modules match the directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you don't want to specify the load path.  You can add lib/tidy to the LOAD_PATH and then Rails will find it, but it's easier to just stick with the conventions